# Few web/HTML5 apps not working on Google Chrome even after clean install

Tags: google-chrome, html5

Most of the problems seem to be with HTML5 applications. I have uninstalled Google Chrome, I removed everything from AppData, cleaned the registry. And then installed.

Cut the Rope and similar apps which are working on other browsers don't work correctly in Chrome.

I have checked the console, everything seems to be fine. Has anybody else faced similar issues? Is there no way to completely reset all settings and have a fresh installation of Chrome?

Everything works as desired in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Thanks in advance.

**Browser Details:**

*Chrome Version: 25.0.1364.172 m*

*Operating System: Windows 8*

*Extensions (type Chrome:extensions into your omnibox): Attachments.me, Cut the Rope, LastPass*

Comment: Can you confirm if this only happens with Chrome - do they work OK in FireFox/ IE?

Comment: Yes. Everything is good in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Does this happen with Chrome on other computers as well?

Comment: No. I use the same Google Account to sync Google Chrome on other computers. All apps work fine there on the other computers.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Could the problem be with your Antivirus/internet security/firewall suite? Have you tried disabling them?

Comment: @gronostaj - By not working I mean that some of the apps don't respond to mouse over or mouse click and drag or mouse click. For example, in the game "Cut the Rope", I cannot cut the rope because none of the mouse actions respond.

Comment: @Mokubai - I doubt if it's an antivirus issue, since I have tried almost every thing. Still I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @AshinMandal I doubt it is an antivirus issue too as you state that Firefox and IE are fine but some internet security suites have aggressive firewalls that block certain things or certain patterns which may affect the browser.  It could be that the website needs a different support library for Chrome which is either not downloading properly due to an internet security suite or rubbish servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the Cache,

```
System -> *advanced* Clear Browsing Data -> [Check] Empty the cache
```

I was having similar issues, to the point where invocation of jQuery scripts (and almost everything else that involved an external script) failed. After restarts, roll backs and re-installs, the above solution was what fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, I have. As I mentioned I uninstalled Google Chrome, I removed everything from AppData, cleaned the registry. And then installed again. Doesn't seem to work.